Not able to download a web page that uses javascript
I have been trying to download a web page that I ultimately intend to scrape. The page uses Javascript, and has in their code a catch to test if javascript is enabled, and I keep getting it is not enabled.
I am trying to do it under wsl2 (ubuntu) on a windows 10 machine. I have tried with selenium, headless chrome, and axios, and am unable to figure out how to get it to execute the javascript.
As I want to put this into my crontab, I am not using any gui.
The website is
https://app.aquahawkami.tech/nfc?imei=359986122021410
Before I start to scrape the output, I figure I have to first get a good download, and that is where I am stuck.
Here is the javascript:
// index.js

const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
axios.get('https://app.aquahawkami.tech/nfc?imei=359986122021410', {responseType: 'document'}).then(response => {
  fs.writeFile('./wm.html', response.data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
});

Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://app.aquahawkami.tech/nfc?imei=359986122021410")

page_source = driver.page_source
print(page_source)
fileToWrite = open("aquahawk_source.html", "w")
fileToWrite.write(page_source)
fileToWrite.close()
driver.close()

finally headless chrome:
`google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://app.aquahawkami.tech/nfc?imei=359986122021410
`

is this the data that you want ?

Yes, that is what I am looking for, and I can manipulate that into a table.  These are new water meters, and I want to grab the page every so often and save.  Can you show me how?

can you clarify what is the expected output? do you want to loop this indefinitely?

Oh I am sorry. No I want it to grab just once, and I will then call the script every 6 hours.

Here's an example of how you can get the data from the api every 6 hours:
async function getMeterData(imei){
  /* 
  this is a template string, it allows constructing/joinning strings cleanly
  in this case it will insert the function argument `imei` into the string
  eg:`https://api.aquahawkami.tech/endpoint?imei=${imei}` --> https://api.aquahawkami.tech/endpoint?imei=359986122021410
  
  more info : 
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
  */
  const url = `https://api.aquahawkami.tech/endpoint?imei=${imei}`;
   
  /* 
  this makes a fetch request (async) to the url.
  r.json() is called after the request(promise) fullfils, and .json() itself returns a promise
  `await` waits until said promise fullfils (now `data` contains the json object)
  
  more info: 
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
  */
  const data = await fetch(url).then(r => r.json());

  /*
  console.log() just prints a message to the console, something like python's print()
  consol.log(data) will print the data (object) to the console.

  more info:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log_static
  */
  console.log(data);

  /*
  this is object destructuring, it is equivalent to this:
  const slp_time = data.attributes.slp_time;
  const reading = data.attributes.reading;
  const lastUpdateTime = data.lastUpdateTime;
  
  more info:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
  */
  const {attributes: {slp_time, reading}, lastUpdateTime} = data;

  /*
  here I convert `slp_time` from a string to an int (parseInt)
  then multiply it by the length of the `reading` array 
  then multiply by 1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds (Date and setTimeout use milliseconds)

  this is simply trying to "dynamically" calculate the 6 hour interval
  if you wish you can replace this line entirely with a hardcoded value
  eg: const interval_ms = 21600000;
  or: const interval_ms = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  */
  const interval_ms =  parseInt(slp_time) * reading.length * 1000; 
  
  /*
  `new Date(lastUpdateTime)` will create a new Date object from the string `lastUpdateTime` (data.lastUpdateTime)
  `.getTime()` will return that date as timestamp (in milliseconds)
  by adding `interval_ms` to that last update timestamp we should get the next update timestamp

  more info:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
  */
  const nextUpdateTime = new Date(lastUpdateTime).getTime() + interval_ms;

  /*
  `new Date().getTime()` will return the CURRENT date and time as a timestamp
  `nextUpdateTime - new Date().getTime()` calculates the different between current time and nextUpdateTime
   now we know how long we have to wait from NOW until the next update
  */
  const wait = nextUpdateTime - new Date().getTime();

  /*
  `setTimeout()` sets a timer and calls the supplied function when the timer runs out,
  it takes a function (to call) and a timeout in milliseconds
  in this case it will call this arrow function: () => getMeterData(imei) after `wait` runs out.
  so basically `getMeterData` creates a timer to call itself after a 6 hours and does that indefinitely

  more info:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
  */
  setTimeout(() => getMeterData(imei), wait);
}

// here we make the first call to the `getMeterData` function with '359986122021410' as the imei argument
getMeterData('359986122021410');

You might prefer to use a scheduler/cronjob instead of setTimeout.
There is also this endpoint that has slightly different data: https://api.aquahawkami.tech/meter?meter=83837540
The difference between the two addresses is that the second one /meter includes a reads and reading arrays that have slightly different formats (string vs int & timestamp), and it also seems to includes the whole data from the first address /endpoint, but the actual values of the readings are the same across arrays/addresses; so you can use whichever one is more convenient.

The second address almost works for me. If you load the web page in a browser you will see 6 readings after the text raw meter read. My housing development is installing new water meters that talk to a central location every 6 or more hours. When the central location gets an update, it gives the central location the meter at hour 1,2,3,4,5,6 with 6 being the current.  Unfortunately I have not yet taken a java class so this is new to me, and as I am almost 71 years old, not sure that I will. Could you give me an explanation of console.log(data) and const {attributes:  is?

@Skibumdon I added comments explaining every line, let me know if anything is still unclear.

Thank you very much GTK2.  I now have a cron job every 6 hours sending me a csv file of the data!!

@Skibumdon glad it helped! if there are no further issues please accept the answer.
